# libxml xmlXPathEvalExpression order

Tags: c, xml, xpath, libxml2

I've started using `libxml` in `C`, and I'm using the `xmlXPathEvalExpression` function to evaluate XPath.

My XML file actually represents a table, with each child node representing a row in that table and its attributes are the corresponding values, so the order is important.

I couldn't find information about that function in regards to its order. Does it return the nodes in the document order

for example, the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <TABLE0>
      <Row Item0="1" Item1="2"/>
      <Row Item0="2" Item1="3"/>
      <Row Item0="3" Item1="4"/>
    </TABLE0>
    <TABLE1>
      <Row Item0="1" Item1="12"/>
      <Row Item0="6" Item1="15"/>
    </TABLE1>
</Root>
```

Can I be sure that after evaluating `/Root/TABLE0/*` and getting the nodeset, calling `nodeSet->nodeTab[0]` would get the first row, `nodeSet->nodeTab[1]` would get the second and so on?

If not, is there a way to sort it by document order?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the results of XPath expressions evaluated with `xmlXPathEvalExpression` or compiled with `xmlXPathCompile` are always sorted in document order. (Internally, they're compiled by calling [`xmlXPathCompileExpr`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/tree/xpath.c?id=07def30fa7d5c5aa73e9d522a2e17bfa7a272df8#n11011) with a *true* sort flag.)