# Does "find" return nodes in order?

Tags: xml, perl, dom, xpath, libxml2

Do `XML::LibXML::Node::find` and related methods *guarantee* that the list of nodes will always be ordered as in the XML document?

This is important for me because my document corresponds to a big array in which I want to be able to delete series of items in certain circumstances, and I must make sure something like this works consistently:

```
my @nodes = $dom->find('//MyElement[@attr=something]/descendant::Token/@id')
                ->get_nodelist;
for my $token ( reverse map { $_->value } @nodes ) {
    splice @my_big_array, $token, 1;
}
```

The difficulty is that this is not documented in [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aNode#find), and I don't know whether this depends on `libxml2` implementation, [whose documentation](http://xmlsoft.org/html/index.html) I don't really understand, or on the [DOM standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html) or some other W3C standard, which were clearly not written to be read my mere mortals.

Comment: Short Answer: Yes.  It's almost so obvious a requirement, that it goes without saying.  But given XPath is ordered, any module that implements XPath would have to follow that requirement as well.  So yes to `XML::Twig`, `XML::LibXML`.  And for separate reasons, but heck even `XML::Simple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I essentially [answered this in a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626947/libxml-xmlxpathevalexpression-order/22664522#22664522). `XML::LibXML` calls `xmlXPathCompile` from *libxml2* which makes sure that the resulting node-set will be sorted in document order.

Answer (score 2):

To my best knowledge the current XML standard does care about the order of the nodes and the current implementaion of XML::LibXML will give you back the same order every time.

See more: [In XML, is order important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131495/in-xml-is-order-important), [Does XML care about the order of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328867/does-xml-care-about-the-order-of-elements)

Good reading about this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-eleord/index.html

1: Its needs to be ordered some way so each run of the same parser should return the same result. 99% of parsers uses the order in xml file the remaining ones orders by the order in the schema

> The XML Information Set (InfoSet -- see Resources), the core XML data
>   model defined by the W3C, characterizes element children as: An
>   ordered list of child information items, in document order.

2: The ordering could enforced or removed

> The ampersand (&) characters between the sibling element subpatterns
>   indicate that any order is acceptable.

```
element memo {
  element title { text } &
  element date { text } &
  element from { text } &
  element to { text } &
  element body { text }
}
```